# Dynamically mapping with Automapper

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, automapper

I'm trying to conditionally map two objects based on `ExtendedField.type`. So if the type is `textbox` then I would map to the `TextBox` class, but if it's `checkbox` then I would map to `Checkbox` class. And of course this needs to be open for extension to map to other IHtmlElement derived types.

```
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ExtendedField, IEnumerable<IHtmlElement>>(extendedFields);
```

A sample of the objects:

```
public class ExtendedField {
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string prompt { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public Interface IHtmlElement {
    string label { get; set; }
    string type { get; set; }
    string value { get; set; }
}

public class TextBox : IHtmlElement {
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get { return "textbox"; } }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBox : IHtmlElement {
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get { return "checkbox"; } }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I have created the mapping to map to `IHtmlElement` but I can't think of how to dynamically tell AutoMapper which concrete class to map to based off the `type` property.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ExtendedField, IHtmlElement>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.label, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.prompt))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.type, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.type))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.extendedFieldValue));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ExtendedField.type you must contain **full qualified type name**.
write type converter:

```
public class ExtFieldToIHtmlElementConverter : TypeConverter<ExtendedField, IHtmlElement>
    {
        protected override IHtmlElement ConvertCore(ExtendedField source)
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(source.type)) as IHtmlElement;
            obj.label = source.prompt;
            obj.value = source.value;

            return obj;
        }
    }
```

mapping:

```
mapper.CreateMap<ExtendedField, IHtmlElement>().ConvertUsing<ExtFieldToIHtmlElementConverter>();
```

example of using:

```
var element = Mapper.Map<IHtmlElement>(extFieldObj); // become instance that implement IHtmlElement interface.
```

Comment: Thank you, I really like this idea but I don't have the freedom to change `ExtendedField.type` value to be the fully qualified name of the class to be mapped to.

Comment: mb you can create helper, that will contains private dictionary with string like "textbox", "checkbox" etc. as a key, and concrete type as a value and public method that become string as param and return  
necessary type for mapping. make some changes in `ExtFieldToIHtmlElementConverter`. see example here: http://pastebin.com/8neMdXhb

Comment: yep, that's exactly the impl I was thinking of :)